# ARIMA with trends and exogenous

Tags: predictive-models, arima, matlab, trend

I'm trying to solve a assignment from an university statistic course regarding the ARIMA models using [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab).

The assignment is:

I have:

- an Y vector of size n of data
- an NxK matrix with a trend and an exogenous variable where N ha the same length of Y and K=2

Having

$$y_t=X_t\beta + \mu_t$$

with the following:

[image]

The first question is to estimate the 3 models.

After plotting the data I observed that the trend is the second column of NxK matrix and so the exogenous is the first.

**Y chart is**
[image]

**Trend chart is**
[image]

**The exogenous chart is**
[image]

As far as I understand (my Professor is very bad....):

- The first model is arimax(0,0,0)
- The second model is arimax(2,0,1)
- The third model is arimax(3,0,2)

Am I right?

Secondly I don't know how to use regARIMA  and estimate commands considering the trend and the exogenous variables.

I come to the following solution, but I'm quite sure it is wrong because I'm considering NxK matrix as previsions of the model

```
% Model 2 ARIMAX(2,0,1) 
mdl_2_p = 2;
mdl_2_q = 1;
mdl_2=regARIMA('AR',nan(mdl_2_p,1), 'MA', nan(mdl_2_q,1), 'Intercept', 0);
[mdl_hat_2,vpar_mdl_2,logl_mdl_2,info_mdl_2]=estimate(mdl_2,Y,'X',X);
```

Comment: Typically, "ARIMAX" is used for a related but slightly different model, what you have there is actually a "regression with ARIMA errors" (or sometimes "regARIMA"). Aside from that, yes your interpretation of the ARIMA orders is correct. The question about the specific Matlab syntax for the function `regARIMA` is off-topic here, but your "N x K matrix" (of regressors) is not a prevision of the model (in fact it is not "modeled", that's what makes it exogenous), if that helps.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaug.  Sorry to be off topic on [tag:matlab] code. Where can I ask for it?

Comment: @ChrisHaug Maybe the exogenous variables must be modeled as linear regression model (fitlm) and then used to perform regARIMA between Y and the fitted value returned by linear regression?